# TypeError: Expected unicode, got datetime.timedelta in pandas 1.1.5

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I've the following code -

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data_dict = {"DATE_1" : [datetime.strptime("01/01/8888", "%m/%d/%Y").date()]*5,
             "DATE_2" : [datetime.strptime("01/01/1000", "%m/%d/%Y").date()]*5}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
df2
```

Now I want to subtract max of the above dates with 07/13/2021 and find the numbers of years between these dates.

```
(df2[["DATE_1", "DATE_2"]].max(axis=1, skipna=True)- datetime.strptime('07/13/2021', "%m/%d/%Y").date()).apply(lambda x: abs(x.days) if not pd.isna(x) else np.NaN)/365.0
```

The above line seems to work with `pandas '0.25.3'`and gives this as output

```
0    6871.032877
1    6871.032877
2    6871.032877
3    6871.032877
4    6871.032877
dtype: float64
```

But when I run it with `pandas '1.1.5'`, I get the following error -

```
TypeError: Expected unicode, got datetime.timedelta

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

Is there any way to calculate the difference? I cannot use datetime64[ns] because of it's limited range.

Comment: cannot reproduce with pandas 1.3.0, output there is just like you describe for 0.25.3.

Comment: @MrFuppes Try on google colab -  that has 1.1.5

Comment: I did, seems that this version of pandas has a problem handling the native Python timedelta datatype. Best advice I can give if you cannot upgrade pandas is do the processing in native Python until you have the delta years as float, then cast back to pd.Series and continue from there.

Comment: @MrFuppes I went ahead and used this. Not an efficient solution but worked for me unless someone else has a better solution

`df2["YEARS"] = [abs((x - datetime.strptime('07/13/2021', "%m/%d/%Y").date()).days)/365.0 if not pd.isna(x) else np.NaN for x in df2[["DATE_1", "DATE_2"]].max(axis=1, skipna=True)]
`